Splitting Sorting and Repacking a column name
I trying to split the fileName and the columnName and then repack them. Instead of having File_Name_Alpha, I want FileNameAlpha. I've been trying using SQL in the notebook and it looked like it was working, but then I'd get some that would repack as AlphaNameFile or FileAlphaName when I want to retain the original order. Same issue for the columnName, Have_A_Great_Day would end up randomly as ADayGreatHave. To make matters worse rarely happens, but I can't have it rarely happen, it needs to always be repacked in the correct order. The problem seems to be in the collect_set where according to databricks is

The order of elements in the array is non-deterministic

So how do I guarantee order when repacking my file and column names? Sample code on what I'm trying:
dfTableOfContents = spark.createDataFrame([ 
    ("File_Name_Alpha", 1, 'Alpha', "int", None), 
    ("File_Name_Alpha", 2, 'One_Two_Three', "nvarchar", "512"),
    ("File_Name_Alpha", 3, 'Have_A_Great_Day', "float", None),
    ("File_Name_Alpha", 4, 'Another_Great_Day', "varchar", "255"),
    ("File_Name_Alpha", 5, 'Greenday_The_Smashing_Pumpkins_Rancid_2024', "float", None),
    ("File_Name_Alpha", 6, 'OAR_Fitz_and_the_Trantrums', "varchar", "MAX"),
    ("File_Name_Alpha", 7, 'Thirty_Seconds_to_Mars', "nvarchar", "8000"),
    ("File_Name_Alpha", 8, 'CROWDED_HOUSE', "numeric", None),
    ("File_Name_Beta", 1, 'PCT_OFF', "bigint", None), 
    ("File_Name_Beta", 2, 'CC_RATE', "nvarchar", "512"),
    ("File_Name_Beta", 3, 'EST_REVENUE', "float", None),
    ("File_Name_Beta", 4, 'COST_EST', "varchar", "255"),
    ("File_Name_Beta", 5, 'FY_2024', "float", None),
    ("File_Name_Beta", 6, 'OVERHEAD', "varchar", "MAX"),
    ("File_Name_Beta", 7, 'SMALL_MEDIUM_LARGE_XL', "nvarchar", "8000"),
    ("File_Name_Gamma", 1, "RAGE_AGAINST_THE_MACHINE", "varchar", "510"),
    ("File_Name_Delta", 1, "ID", "int", None),
    ("File_Name_Delta", 2, "GROUPLOVE", "varchar", "MAX"),
    ("File_Name_Delta", 3, "STING", "money", None),
    ("File_Name_Delta", 4, "CERT_DATE", "date", None),
    ("File_Name_Epsilon", 1, "Every_Cloud_Has_A_Silver_Lining", "varchar", "MAX"),
    ("File_Name_Epsilon", 2, "Break_A_Leg", "varchar", "MAX"),
    ("File_Name_Epsilon", 3, "Piece_Of_Cake", "varchar", "MAX"),
    ("File_Name_Epsilon", 4, "On_The_Same_Page", "varchar", "MAX"),
    ("File_Name_Epsilon", 5, "Speak_Of_The_Devil", "varchar", "MAX"),
    ("File_Name_Epsilon", 6, "Burning_The_Midnight_Oil", "varchar", "MAX"),
    ("File_Name_Epsilon", 7, "Actions_Speak_Louder_Than_Words", "varchar", "MAX"),
    ("File_Name_Epsilon", 8, "Better_Late_Than_Never", "varchar", "MAX"),
    ("File_Name_Epsilon", 9, "Hit_The_Nail_On_The_Head", "varchar", "MAX"),
    ("File_Name_Epsilon", 10, "Under_The_Weather", "varchar", "MAX")

], schema='FileName string, OrdinalPosition integer, ColumnName string, DataType string, CharacterMaximumLength string') 

print (dfTableOfContents)
dfTableOfContents.show()
display (dfTableOfContents)
dfTableOfContents.createOrReplaceTempView("TableOfContents")

Dataframe 2:
dfReplacement = spark.createDataFrame([ 
    ("CERT", "Certification"), 
    ("FY", "FiscalYear"),
    ("CC", "CreditCard"),
    ("EST", "Estimate"),
    ("PCT", "Percent") ,
    ("XL", "ExtraLarge")

], schema='Abbreviation string, Original string') 

print (dfReplacement)
dfReplacement.show()
display (dfReplacement)
dfReplacement.createOrReplaceTempView("Replacement")

Code with the troublesome collect_set
%sql
-- First capture the max column length for each table, used to make output line up/pretty print
WITH MaxColumnLengthCTE
  AS (SELECT `FileName`
           , max(len(trim(`ColumnName`))) AS `MaxColumnLength`
        FROM
             TableOfContents
             AS `Rows`
       GROUP BY `FileName`)
-- Capture all the Columns  
, ColumnsCTE
  AS (SELECT      Rows.*
                , concat(CASE
                       WHEN `OrdinalPosition` = 1 THEN ' '
                       ELSE ',' END, '`', `ColumnName`, '` ', space(mcl.`MaxColumnLength` - len(`ColumnName`)), 'NVARCHAR(', CASE
                                                                                                                                          WHEN `DataType` = 'varchar' THEN `CharacterMaximumLength`
                                                                                                                                          ELSE CASE
                                                                                                                                                    WHEN `DataType` IN ( 'int', 'money', 'float' ) THEN '25'
                                                                                                                                                    ELSE 'MAX' END END, ')') AS `WithColumn`
        FROM
                  TableOfContents
                                     AS `Rows`
       INNER JOIN MaxColumnLengthCTE mcl ON mcl.`FileName` = Rows.`FileName`
   )
-- Capture the View Name   
      , ViewNameCTE
  AS (
SELECT `ViewNameParts`.`FileName`
, array_join(collect_set(`ViewNameParts`.value) , '') AS `ViewName` 
FROM (
  SELECT
    cte.`FileName`,
    array_join(split(cte.`FileName`, '_'),'') AS `value`
  FROM ColumnsCTE cte) AS `ViewNameParts`
GROUP BY `ViewNameParts`.`FileName`)
-- Capture All the portions of the columns names.
, ColumnNamePartsCTE
  AS (
SELECT       `ColumnNameParts`.`FileName`
                 , `ColumnNameParts`.`OrdinalPosition`
                 , concat(upper(substring(`ColumnNameParts`.value, 1, 1)), lower(substring(`ColumnNameParts`.value, 2, len(`ColumnNameParts`.value)))) AS `ColumnNamePart`
                 , `ColumnNameParts`.ColumnOrdinal
FROM (
  SELECT
    cte.`FileName`,
    cte.`OrdinalPosition`,
    explode(split(cte.`ColumnName`, '_')) AS `value`,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 1,2) AS `ColumnOrdinal`
  FROM ColumnsCTE cte) AS `ColumnNameParts`
  GROUP BY `ColumnNameParts`.`FileName`, `ColumnNameParts`.`OrdinalPosition`, `ColumnNameParts`.value, `ColumnNameParts`.ColumnOrdinal
  ORDER BY `ColumnNameParts`.`FileName`, `ColumnNameParts`.`OrdinalPosition`, `ColumnNameParts`.ColumnOrdinal
 )
, ColumnNameCTE
 AS (
    SELECT cte.`FileName`
           , cte.`OrdinalPosition`
           , concat('`', array_join(collect_set(CASE
                                   WHEN rep.`Original` IS NOT NULL THEN rep.`Original`
                                   ELSE cte.`ColumnNamePart` END
                            ), ''), '`') AS `ColumnName`
        FROM ColumnNamePartsCTE cte
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
             Replacement
                                AS rep ON upper(rep.`Abbreviation`) = upper(`ColumnNamePart`)
       GROUP BY cte.`FileName`
              , cte.`OrdinalPosition`
       ORDER BY cte.`FileName`
              , cte.`OrdinalPosition`              
) 
, MaxLengthCTE
 AS (
    SELECT      c.`FileName`
                , max(len(trim(c.`ColumnName`)))                                         AS `MaxColumnLength`
                , max(len(cn.`ColumnName`))                                             AS `ColumnNameMaxLength`
                , max(len(CASE
                               WHEN c.`DataType` <> 'varchar' THEN c.`DataType` ELSE '' END)) AS `DataTypeMaxLength`
        FROM      ColumnNameCTE AS cn
       INNER JOIN ColumnsCTE    AS c ON c.`OrdinalPosition` = cn.`OrdinalPosition`
                                    AND c.`FileName`        = cn.`FileName`
       GROUP BY c.`FileName`
)
, ViewPartsCTE
AS (
    SELECT      c.`FileName`
                , c.`OrdinalPosition`
                , concat(CASE
                       WHEN c.`OrdinalPosition` = 1 THEN ' '
                       ELSE ',' END, CASE
                                           WHEN c.`DataType` IN ('varchar', 'nvarchar') THEN concat('`', c.`ColumnName`, '`')
                                           ELSE concat('CAST (`', c.`ColumnName`, '` ', space(ml.`MaxColumnLength` - len(c.`ColumnName`)), 'AS ', upper(c.`DataType`), ')') END
                  , CASE
                         WHEN c.`DataType` IN ('varchar', 'nvarchar') THEN space(ml.`MaxColumnLength` + 11 + ml.`DataTypeMaxLength` - len(c.`ColumnName`))
                         ELSE concat(space(ml.`DataTypeMaxLength` - len(c.`DataType`))) END, ' AS ', cn.`ColumnName`) AS `CastedColumnName`
                , c.`WithColumn`
        FROM      ColumnNameCTE AS cn
       INNER JOIN ColumnsCTE    AS c ON c.`OrdinalPosition` = cn.`OrdinalPosition`
                                    AND c.`FileName`        = cn.`FileName`
       INNER JOIN MaxLengthCTE  ml ON ml.`FileName`         = c.`FileName`
       ORDER BY c.`FileName`
                , c.`OrdinalPosition`
)
select `ViewName` 
       ,Concat('CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW dev_silver.ThirdPartyData.', `ViewName`, ' AS', '\n', 'SELECT ', '\n'
            , array_join(sort_array(collect_list(struct(`OrdinalPosition`, item_score))).item_score, '\n')
            , '\n', 'FROM', '\n', 'parquet.`abfss://datalake@', 'storageaccountname'
            , '.dfs.core.windows.net/Silver/ThirdPartyData/', `FileName`, '`'
         )
          AS `CreateViewStatement`
from (
        select vn.`ViewName`
               ,vp.`CastedColumnName`
               ,vp.`OrdinalPosition`
               ,vp.`FileName`
               ,concat(vp.`CastedColumnName`) as item_score
          FROM      ViewPartsCTE vp
          INNER JOIN ViewNameCTE  AS vn ON vn.`FileName` = vp.`FileName`
     ) t0  
--WHERE t0.`FileName` = '$TableName'
 GROUP BY t0.`FileName`
        , t0.`ViewName`
 ORDER BY t0.`FileName`
         , t0.`ViewName`;


If your FileName and ColumnName column doesn't haverepeated words use can use collect_list() as this function maintains order.

Can you post an example of expected input and ouput?

collect_list() is out as column names can contain repeated words
